# Makefiles: mixed file/directory patterns

Tags: makefile

I have a `Makefile` and the following directory structure:

```
mkdir a
echo 1 > a/b
```

And the rules (this creates a file `b` from `a/b`, and it works fine):

```
all: ./b

./b: a/b
   echo $^ > $@
```

When I want to replace `/b` by a `%`-pattern, it stops working ("`no rule`"):

```
all: ./b

.%: a%
    echo $^ > $@
```

Why?

```
./%: a/%  # works fine
```

Is there some rule that a pattern that corresponds to files can not be used for directories and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [How Patterns Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html),

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does
>   not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name
>   before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the
>   comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory
>   names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the
>   prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule’s prerequisite
>   patterns and the file name.

So for the failure case, ".%" means to match any target's filename starting with ".".

Comment: Thanks, I read this sentence before and was not sure what it meant (to be fair, it was late and I was tired). Is there any way to get around this in order to introduce a pattern-like rule like the one above? (apart from a `foreach` loop creating all targets explicitly)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, maybe you could update your question to clarify it.